# Declare column in variable is not working in Optic query MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I am trying to declare the column in a variable and want to call that variable inside my program.
Here is my optic query code which returns me - Column not found.
Please help to understand the problem in my query.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
import module namespace ofn="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/fn" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-fn.xqy";
import module namespace osql="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/sql" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-sql.xqy";  
declare option xdmp:mapping "false";
let $view := op:from-view("GTM2_Shipment", "Shipment_View")
let $count := op:view-col("Shipment_View", "Ancillary_QuotePrice")
return $view
=> op:where(op:and((
                   op:gt(op:col("$count"), 0)

                   ))
                   )
=> op:group-by("transMode", op:count("QuotePrice", "$count"))
=> op:result()
```

here is the result I get -

```
[1.0-ml] SQL-NOCOLUMN: Column not found: $count
Stack Trace
At line 1 column 2:
In sem:execute(plan:sparql(" * { sample(transMode) AS transMode) count($count) AS QuotePrice) { FILTER ($count gt xs:integer(&quot;0&quot;) and fn:format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(BookingCreateDt), xs:string(&quot;[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]&quot;)) gt sql:dateadd(xs:string(&quot;month&quot;), xs:int(&quot;-6&quot;), fn:format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(&quot;2022-06-30T10:42:50.2654743+01:00&quot;), xs:string(&quot;[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]&quot;)))) } GROUP BY transMode }"), (), ()
```

I have also tried to declare the column like this-
let $count := op:col("Ancillary_QuotePrice")
And it doesnot recognize the column from the view and gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once `$count` is defined as an `op:view-col()`, then just use it as a variable. See suggestions below:

- `op:gt(op:col("$count"), 0)` ---change to--> `op:gt($count, 0)`
- `op:count("QuotePrice", "$count")` ---change to--> `op:count("QuotePrice", $count)`

Comment: Thanks David, it works as expected :-)

Comment: Great. Glad to hear it.  Optic API can be daunting at times, but once you get into it, it has quite a  bit of power.